# How to update speed value only if a character is moving in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

How can I update a players speed only when they are moving (its just easier on the computer than a `while true do` loop)
I have this:

```
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

while humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 do
  humanoid.WalkSpeed = player.leaderstats.Speed.Value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use loops in a game that provides events. This loop will get your code stuck anyway.

The only moment you need to change the speed is when the leader speed changes. So why not implement a handler for the Changed event that updates the other players' speeds.

Example:

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/NumberValue/Changed

```
local function printValue(value)
    print(value)
end
 
Workspace.NumberValue.Changed:Connect(printValue)
 
Workspace.NumberValue.Value = 20
```